# How to get the number of commits on a file from all authors cumulatively

Tags: git

In other words, what `git log --follow <file>` does, but for all authors together.

For example, if "contributor1" commits to a file 5 times, and I do it 3, the result should be 8 for that file.

Comment: what do you want for your answer?  a list of authors?  a list of authors with counts per author?  or just a single number total: number of authors who committed to this file?

Comment: Just the total number of commits. I'm trying to track activity on a file, and it seems like files with an excessive number of commits could be candidates for refactoring.

Comment: I just realized my question was incorrect. I updated it so it has the correct git command.

Comment: So you want to count the number of commits in the output of the command you gave?  In this case, go with Wolf's answer – add the `--oneline` output format for `git log` and count the number of lines in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the total number of commits to a given file, even through renames, by combining `git log` with `wc`:

```
git log --follow --oneline -- filename | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

One option to get the number of commits for each file would be

```
git log --format=format: --name-only | sort | uniq -c
```

This lists the files that were changed in each commit, then groups by file name and counts the occurrences.

If you just want to know the number of commits for a single file, you can use

```
git rev-list --count HEAD -- <filename>
```